# Issue with .pc files, Libs rendering incorrectly

Tags: ros, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using osc / OpenSUSE OBS to build RPM packages of catkin for OpenSUSE. In my .spec file, I am doing something like this (for example, with the message_generation package):

```
%setup -q -c -n workspace
mv * message_generation
mkdir src
mv message_generation src

%build
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr catkin_make_isolated --install
```

The issue I am currently having is that the way the code is written for catkin, my message_generation.pc file in the workspace/install_isolated directory looks like this:

```
Description: Description of message_generation
Version: 0.2.10
Cflags: 
Libs: -L/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/workspace/install_isolated/lib 
Requires: gencpp genlisp genmsg genpy
```

I would like Libs to be -L/usr/lib, where I am planning on moving the lib directory, but instead, I am seeing that build environment path, which shouldn't happen. How can I go about doing this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92811/issue-with-.pc-files,-libs-rendering-incorrectly/) by [duffany1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4288/duffany1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2013-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use the --install-space argument to install into /usr/lib instead of the default install_isolated.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1